# Time complexity of while some condition is true:

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

In python, what is the time complexity for the very first line in

```
While x==true:
    line
    line
    if something is equal to something:
         x=false
         return something
```

I'm guessing it may be O(n) as it depends on the number of iterations based on the input

Comment: What do you mean by "is there a time complexity"? nothing happens in zero-time. For this case the time complexity is O(1).

Answer (score -1):

If you have an upper bound on the number of iterations for that if condition to be true, it would be that. For example if incrementing the value of `something` with each iteration of the loop.

However, if it is more complex than just only incrementing every iteration (no decrementing), then this is known as the halting problem and there is no known upper bound.

Comment: In the case there is a halting problem there is no time complexity either?

Comment: The time complexity is infinity. As that's the upper bound and cannot be lowered. I want to point out that you can decrement the value of `something` but the series *must* converge to the value that you're looking to stop at.

Comment: Say i implemented a binary search within that while loop and when the value is found x is changed to false. Would the complexity be O(log n) since it depends on the binary search?